# Google Calendar Reminders Sharesheet

Tags: google-calendar-api, x-callback-url

I'm using Apple's Shortcuts and am trying to make a sharesheet item that will add a reminder to Google Calendar. I have been able to ascertain that I can open the calendar with `googlecalendar://`, but I cannot find details on the app methods beyond the `create event` and `view event` ones listed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9ifjz7/all_google_app_urls_and_callback_urls/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=ios_share_flow_optimization&utm_term=enabled).

Are all the x-callback-url methods documented somewhere obvious that I am missing, or is there a method by which to find these somewhere?

Further research suggested I use `Apple Configurator 2` to get an IPA file on the next app update. I installed it on my desktop but I am away from home with only VPN access to the desktop and wouldn't be able to plug my phone into it even if an update were available.

I am imagining something like `com.google.calendar://?action=reminder&title={{myTitle}}`...